# Disabling unique constraint on a column in a table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to disable a unique constraint on an alias column but fail,

```
ALTER TABLE #_epc_items drop index `alias`
```

The flow is as follows: I checkboxed the column, clicked 'unique', success.
Than executed the above SQL, still got success, But, even though i got a success message, the column is STILL unique. Now, when i try to execute the above SQL again, i get an error:

```
 #1091 - Can't DROP 'alias'; check that column/key exists
```

And the column clearly exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: The only way I see your *alter* not getting a 1064 error in mysql is if you wrapped the funky table name with back-ticks. In which case a 1091 would suggest the key name is not the one in force

Comment: I do get a 1091. What do you mean "not the one in force" ?

Comment: please see http://pastebin.com/iCudJ5Hb, and try to raise the bar on how you get to where you get in the future :p

Comment: That did the trick :) 10x buddy.